# How to subset a table in R?

Tags: r, plot

I want to create a mosaic plot in R using `mosaic` from the `vcd` library. The table that I am plotting has many many 0's in it (when I plot it, the mosaic plot is incomprehensible), and I would like to create a mosaic plot with just the top 25 highest entries. How do you subset a table in R to accomplish this? Or, how do you change every entry satisfying a certain condition to 0?

As an example:

```
df <- data.frame(letters=c("a","b","c","c","b","c","a","b"), end=c("x","y","x","y","x","y","y","x"))
t <- table(df)
```

The table looks like this:

```
> t
         end
 letters x y
       a 1 1
       b 2 1
       c 1 2
```

I would like to substitute each 1 to be a 0. How should I do this?

Answer (score 3):

The replace each 1 with a 0:

```
t[t==1] <- 0
```

Comment: Thank you! Another quick question: Do you know how to sort the columns in table? As in rearranging the order of the columns based on a certain row of values in the table?